# Can TortoiseHg 2.x be configured to save filter or "Branch" drop-down settings?

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg, tortoisehg-2.0

I'd like to almost always ignore non-default branches when using TortoiseHg 2.x.  Currently every time I open TortoiseHg the filter text entry and Branch drop-down are reset to blank and "* Show all *".

Can TortoiseHg 2.0 save these settings?  Or have a default setting for either?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of TortoiseHg v2.1.1 there is no setting which saves branch or revision set filters between sessions.  They are set to their default value every time TortoiseHg is started.  I have not heard any plans to add such a feature either.

You could open a feature request on the [issue tracker](https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg/issues/?kind=bug&status=open) or email the [discussion](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/tortoisehg-discuss) or [developers](http://groups.google.com/group/thg-dev?pli=1) list asking if there are any undocumented ways to do the job.

Comment: Thanks for the info and the links.  I added a request https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg/issue/1009/workbench-persistence-of-filter-and-or .

Comment: Steve Borho confirmed your answer from the enhancement request.  Thanks again for your quick and helpful response!